# Find intuitive image orientation with opencv

Tags: opencv

I have a bunch of images of handtools and I would like to reorient the pictures along the "intuitive" axis. So what I am trying is to find the magenta line:

[image]

Eventually I was able to feed `fitLine` with the main contour of this hammer, but the middle line does not pass by the center of this hammer:

[image]

Here the sample image for the scissors:

[image]

Comment: What's the shape of `u`?

Comment: @DanMašek `u` is the binary black & white scissors image

Comment: That's the problem, it should be a list of coordinates, either 2D or 3D.

Comment: @DanMašek such as a contour?

Comment: Yes. As as numpy array, for `N` points, it would have shape (N,1,2) or (N,1,3).

Comment: Probably running `findNonZero` on the mask and feeding the output to `fitLine` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @DanMašek I think you found my issue. It works much better now with `fitLine` !

Comment: maybe something like "the median direction of the medial axis"? But you might have to handle symmetry in special.